# eBay: Trading API vs Shopping API

Tags: ebay-api

I'm kind of new with the eBay API. I found two methods to get item information:

1. Trading API has `GetItem` method
2. Shopping API has `GetSingleItem` method

So, what is the main difference between these two APIs?

I need to search items in eBay through my website, I'm making it with the `findingItemsAdvance`. I also need to get the weight and item dimensions in order to calculate the right price, but the `findingItems` doesn't provide it.
The eBay's team advice is use the Trading API, but I don't understand the main difference between the two APIs. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a two part question. *Part 1* is, what is the difference between the two calls. *Part 2* is, what is the difference between the Trading and Shopping API.

Lets start with *Part 2* first.

The **Trading API** is the "full featured" API. It can do just about everything you would want to do with eBay. Because the **Trading API** can do everything, it is longer, and to an extent, more unwieldy. (Edit: The trading API can't do everything, it is limited to your user only)

The **Shopping API** is not your general purpose eBay toolkit. It is focused, it provides Shopping related functionality and that is it. Thus the calls are generally simpler and easier to work with.

Moving back to *Part 1*, we can see an excellent example of this.

The **Trading API**'s [getItem](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#Response) call has a output listing that clocks in at **739** lines.

The **Shopping API**'s [getSingleItem](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#Response) call has an output listing that clocks in at **242** lines.

This is an example of the increased *strength and complexity* that the **Trading API** offers. The Trading API is the better all around choice, while the **Shopping API** is good for well, a "Shopping" related app.